# Any good resources for creating Visual Slick macros?

Tags: slickedit

Does any one know any good resources for creating Visual Slick macros?

Answer (score 2):

I'd start with the [official community forum](http://community.slickedit.com/index.php?board=4.0) for SlickEdit macros.

Answer (score 1):

After the community forum - I would find the macros directory and go to town looking at all the .e files.  Depending on what you want to do - there is a lot of samples in the actual implementation (just the same way I would do it for emacs).

For example, many years ago I wanted to have something like 'project-load' (dialog that lets you open from all files in the project) but instead of project files - let me open any of the currently checked-out files (not just open, but also diff etc), went and found the project-load source and used that as a sample on implementing a similar dialog

Answer (score 0):

This is a great resource to start with. I wrote my first one [here](http://blog.slickedit.com/2010/04/lets-make-a-macro-part-1-outputting-debug-values/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a book by John Hurst, 'Professional SlickEdit',ISBN-13: 978-0-470-12215-0  that is useful to get you started.